# Find the nth Fibonacci prime in the shortest code in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, primes, fibonacci

I was asked this question in a recent interview. I was able to answer but the interviewer was not impressed at all and moved to the next question.

So I need to find the nth Fibonacci prime number. This is my understanding: we generate a fibonacci series and then store the prime numbers within those series in an array; and for nth prime we iterate and return the nth number in the array. Is this correct?

```
function fibonacci ($number)
{
    if ($number==0)
        return 0;
    if ($number ==1)
        return 1;
    if ($number>=2)
    {
        return fibonacci($number-1)+fibonacci($number-2);
    }
}
function is_prime ($num)
{
    if ($num <2)
        return;
    if ($num >=2)
    {
        $floor = floor (sqrt($num));
        for ($i=2 ; $i <=$floor ; $i++)
        {
            if ($num % $i == 0) // number has factors
                return; // so return
        }
        return $num;
    }
}
$series = array();
for ($i=0 ; $i<24 ; $i++) // randomly used 24
{
    $series[] = fibonacci($i);
}
function fibonacci_prime($s)
{
    $final = array_map ("is_prime", $s);
    // array_filter because we don't want to see null elements
    echo '<pre>',print_r(array_filter($final)),'</pre>';
}
fibonacci_prime($series);

output
Array
(
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 5
    [7] => 13
    [11] => 89
    [13] => 233
    [17] => 1597
    [23] => 28657
)
1
```

I'm wondering if there are better ways to achieve this?

Comment: This guy wrote one, https://swapneshsinha.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/fibonacci-series-in-php/.

Comment: why not use use settype($foo, "integer") and then run through the array using array_push with something like current() + prev()?

Comment: @nomistic could you elaborate?

Comment: as a fibonacci sequence is using an array of numbers where the next number is the sum of the previous two numbers, and you can use settype to define the item as an integer, you could add a new value to the array, based on the value of the previous two items in the array.  I'm not sure exactly how to do it, but this seems like it should work

Comment: as for the prime piece, that makes it more difficult.  that has to be most insane interview question ever.  I think maybe the interviewer wanted to see how fast you could think on your feet.   come to think of it, this assumes you could start at the beginning of the sequence, and that may not always be the case, unless you already had a fibonnacci array.  So the above suggestion could get you the array, and then you could identify what the next number in the sequence, but also make sure it is indivisible by anything.  ok that's nuts.

Comment: A faster way is to calculate the ith fib number with  matrix exponentiation, here is a great article: http://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms